# Swing - Manage multiple listener chain on same button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a Swing GUI in witch every button has its own listener. After, I added another listener that executes a common logic for a set of buttons: ask to save form data before performing the selected operation.

I made it simply:

```
myButton.addActionListener(commonListener);
myButton.addActionListener(customListener);
```

The problem now is that when the logic in the common listener fails (or when the user aborts the operation), I need to prevent the other listeners to be invoked. How can I do that?

Comment: revise your logic: it's **wrong** to rely on order of listener notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest a something like following to achieve your goal.

Rather than having two action listeners, you can have a single action listener and inherit the common functionality through a class hierarchy.

You can have a parent class as following

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public abstract class AbstractButtonActionListener 
                                implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(commonActionPerformed(e)){
            customActionPerfroemd(e);
        }
    }

    public abstract void customActionPerfromed(ActionEvent e);


    /**
     * 
     * @param e
     * @return true if the custom aciton should be performed
     */
    public boolean commonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //method implementation
    }

}
```

The `commonActionPerformed` method would handle the common logic and return true if the flow should continue. Now you can add an action listener to the button as follows

```
button.addActionListener(new AbstractButtonActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void customActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //perform the custom logic here
    }
});
```